# Custom CSS via controller returning via #show/n?format=css but not #show/n.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am implementing a custom theming issue for a Rails 3.2 app, with a very small number of CSS overrides for each theme.

While I have so far implemented the theme variations by inlining some CSS (including occasional Erb parameters) within the layout file, I'd really like to tidy this up by delivering the customisation CSS via a GET request, e.g.: (assume `current_theme` is defined)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag theme_path(current_theme, format: :css) %>
```

In my themes_controller.rb:

```
class ThemesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :css
  ...
  def show
    @theme = Theme.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @theme
  end
end
```

I have the requisite `show.css.erb` file in `views/themes`.

My main issue is that `/themes/1?format=css` loads and renders the CSS file correctly. However, `/themes/1.css` – the form of URL generated by the `theme_path` helper – is producing a 404.

I'm probably overlooking something *very* simple here – hopefully a fellow SO user can point out the bloomin' obvious to prevent my head and brick walls becoming better acquainted...

**UPDATE:** Doing a bot of Rails route recognition debugging:

```
r = Rails.application.routes
#=> #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fc385016170>
r.recognize_path '/themes/1.css'
#=> {:action=>"show", :controller=>"themes", :id=>"1", :format=>"css"}
r.recognize_path '/themes/1?format=css'
#=> {:action=>"show", :controller=>"themes", :id=>"1"}
```

So the fact that `?format=css` seems to be working is actually because, at least when CURLing from the command line, `/themes/1` is returning the requisite CSS. As far as I'm concerned, that's a red herring...

Incidentally, adding this line to `routes.rb` works:

```
  get '/themestyle/:id' => 'themes#show', as: 'themestyle', format: 'css'
```

(using a slightly different route so as not to conflict with the `resources :themes` in routes.rb). `themestyle_path(current_theme)` generates a workable route of – `/themestyle/1` – I can add the 'text/css' type header at render stage no problem. I'll have to hand-code a `<link rel="stylesheet">` element though, as stylesheet_link_tag adds the css suffix.

Comment: I just tested out a few things on a local server, and with standard routes, going to `/themes/1.css` resolves correctly to the theme show route with format css.  Whats your route file look like for the themes?

Comment: Hi Michael – I was just using `resources :themes`. And you're right, that URL is correctly resolving. But I'm getting a Not Found returning back when actually requesting the URL – and it doesn't even seem to hit the server, according to the local logs...

Comment: Interesting that the logs wouldn't even show a request being made, are you sure its requesting from the correct domain?? (Not sure how you could accidentally request from another domain, but thats my only thought as to why the local logs aren't showing a request)

Comment: Absolutely sure - I'm using localhost:3000 in all cases. It's very weird – I'm now wondering whether there's any middleware which is preventing the CSS request from being serviced...

Comment: Are you using the Quiet Assets gem?  It turns off logging for assets, however i'm not sure if the method of obtaining the css that you're using will fall under that or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem: the [rack-zippy](https://github.com/eliotsykes/rack-zippy) gem, middleware designed to help deliver GZIPped production assets on heroku.

Disabling that middleware enables the routes to all work perfectly fine and be passed to the correct controller method with all formats, etc. retained.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but I see your error is that you're trying to use a `controller action` to do the job of a `helper`

Controller actions are only called on HTTP requests, and it's my experience that you cannot just call an action by linking to it from your view / layout -- you have to explicitly call the action, either through the backend, or through ajax or something

---

**Change Your Action To A Helper**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag theme(current_theme) %>


#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def theme
    return theme_path(params[:id])
end
helper_method :theme
```

---

I don't know if this will generate the route correctly, but it's certainly the method I would use

Comment: `theme_path` is a helper function in its own right – wrapping it inside another helper function won't really help.

Comment: True, true, but I hope my idea will give more idea about what you can do